# Testing the primality of Mersenne and Fermat numbers using third order recurrence relation

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, elementary-proofs

Can you prove or disprove the claims given below?

Inspired by [generalization of Lucas-Lehmer test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lucas-LehmerTest.html) I have formulated the following claims:

> **Claim 1** Let $M_p=2^p-1$ where $p$ is an odd prime number , let $S_k=3S_{k-1}-5S_{k-2}+3S_{k-3}$ with $S_0=0 , S_1=1 , S_2=2$ , then $$M_p \text{ is prime iff } \operatorname{GCD}\left(S_{(M_p+1)/2},M_p\right)=1 \text{ and } S_{M_p+1} \equiv 0 \pmod{M_p}$$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1jrEKgzAURXe_IjhIYhSTSKfXN3bM5F5oNW1FjcGndCj990ah272Hc-FWObv41S3s5tncdSws_eSY36Z7ZHmVBKwhsWiuodSQNHwQ-CGFCkijBjJoYIzK-9WPjo9nHArCOidTnnLSMqZoKiS9-2T2AcEopYDFrdviOQn4Jv2DP9uON5xbqUVlRGEFomZZxuy88x0fTBXxoF95evxMxb-28xRm6teIBPwATqA81Q==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

> **Claim 2** Let $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ where $n>1$ , let $S_k=3S_{k-1}-5S_{k-2}+3S_{k-3}$ with $S_0=0 , S_1=1 , S_2=2$ , then $$F_n \text{ is prime iff } \operatorname{GCD}\left(S_{(F_n-1)/2},F_n\right)=1 \text{ and } S_{F_n-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{F_n}$$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw1j7sOgzAMRXe-IuqAEh6CBHVyPZatEzsSoilEQEAxbYeq_94EqZN9j48lu0jY1e7asY5tK5ndvJjxefBkcLoLk33sLFutZkkRWVQQ1aha1dpUQtTwSeCHSiyBJEog5YUZK3iPZtZ8vuCUEVYJqfyckEx9580SSQafVFggmNNUgNP701lOAr6RefChv_OG8zqXolAiqwWiZHHMbmvgAR-szDbnD-YnXxZ9Ev_Yr8vxj0cCfrFpQwc=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Note that I verified these claims only for small values of $M_p$ and $F_n$ because computation of $\operatorname{GCD}$ takes a lot of time.

Comment: Notice that $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a\bmod b,b)$. That is, you can restrict computation of $S_k$ only to modulo $M_p$ (or $F_n$) and still compute the gcd.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks!

Comment: In fact, the sequence $S_k$ satisfy a second-order recurrence: $$S_k = 2S_{k-1} - 3S_{k-2}.$$